# .NET Assembly.Load/LoadFrom fails if calling it within a windows service .net executable

Tags: .net, wpf, windows-services, .net-assembly

**Hi Devs!**

I'm currently a bit lost in loading a specific assembly using "**Assembly.Load**" or "**Assembly.LoadFrom**" within my WPF application during runtime.

**Loading the assembly during runtime works if i just run the executable!**

**But** it throws an exception **"FileNotFoundException, Could not load file or assembly .. or one of it dependencies.."**
 if I load the same assembly the same way with my WPF application running as **windows service** (under LocalSystem).

```
processInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
processInstaller.Username = null;
processInstaller.Password = null;
```

The assembly causing the exception is called "*Siemens.Sinumerik.Operate.Services.Wrapper.dll*" which is referenced by "*Siemens.Sinumerik.Operate.Services.dll*".

*-> 3rd party assembly - no source available and for me it seems the wrapper is a mixed cli/c++ assembly.*

Now after some research to this issue, I found out that .e.g maybe the lookup directory for assemblies is "C:\windows\system32" instead of the folder where the exceutable is stored. Or to take "fuslogvw" to narrow down the issue.

However its not my first project loading assemblies during runtime for some execution. Only thing is i never loaded a mixed "cli/c++" assembly during runtime 
-> There may be any known issues or something i may miss to load the "cli/c++" assembly correctly ?

Here is the code i use to load the assembly (either from file or gac)

```
LoadAssembly("Siemens.Sinumerik.Operate.Services"); // this assembly references the wrapper
LoadAssembly("Siemens.Sinumerik.Operate.Services.Wrapper, Version=4.8.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bdd90fa02fd1c4ee", false); // load the wrapper from GAC using AssemblyName -> Exception only in service
LoadAssembly("Siemens.Sinumerik.Operate.Services.Wrapper"); // load the wrapper from file using AssemblyName -> Exception only in service
```

**LoadAssembly** is checking whether the AssemblyName is already loaded in the current AppDomain and if not, its getting loaded either using GAC or FileSystem (depends on 2nd parameter "loadFromFile" of function LoadAssembly).

Thus it uses either `"Assembly.Load(assemblyName); // from gac"` or `"Assembly.LoadFrom(file); // from file"`

**What I have tried to fix the issue:**

- Referencing the dynamically loaded assemblys to the main-project with the hope the application is able to load the wrapper assembly into the AppDomain during startup -> **fail**
- changing current directory to the path where the wrapper assembly dll is stored -> **fail**
- hooking up all AssemblyLoad and Resolve events and trying to load using "Assembly.Load" -> **fail**
- compared the AppDomains used either for the Service and the normal Executable -> seems both are liky the same didnt see any special difference between them) -> **fail**
- using "fuslogvw" to get some Assembly-Binding information which may indicates any error -> **fail** (see logs below)

Additionally I used "fuslogvw" to find out what the hell is going wrong for the wrapper, but i dont get any clue as the log shows the same result as if I just run the normal executable (which works not as service)
Here is the log **"Siemens.Sinumerik.Operate.Services.Wrapper, Version=4.8.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bdd90fa02fd1c4ee.HTM"**:

```
*** Protokolleintrag für Assembly-Binder  (13.12.2019 @ 12:12:21) ***

Der Vorgang wurde durchgeführt.
Ergebnis der Bindung: hr = 0x0. Der Vorgang wurde erfolgreich beendet.

Der Assemblymanager wurde geladen aus:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Als EXE-Datei ausgeführt.  C:\Projekte\MTF\trunk\MTFMain\MTF\bin\Debug\MTF.exe
--- Ein detailliertes Fehlerprotokoll folgt. 

=== Zustandsinformationen vor Bindung ===
LOG: DisplayName = Siemens.Sinumerik.Operate.Services.Wrapper, Version=4.8.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bdd90fa02fd1c4ee
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Projekte/MTF/trunk/MTFMain/MTF/bin/Debug/
LOG: Ursprünglicher PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: DynamicBase = NULL
LOG: CacheBase = NULL
LOG: AppName = MTF.exe
Aufruf von Assembly : MTF, Version=2.0.7286.21871, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: Diese Bindung startet im default-Load-Kontext.
LOG: Die Anwendungskonfigurationsdatei wird verwendet: C:\Projekte\MTF\trunk\MTFMain\MTF\bin\Debug\MTF.exe.Config
LOG: Die Hostkonfigurationsdatei wird verwendet: 
LOG: Die Computerkonfigurationsdatei von C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config wird verwendet.
LOG: Verweis nach der Richtlinie: Siemens.Sinumerik.Operate.Services.Wrapper, Version=4.8.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bdd90fa02fd1c4ee
LOG: Die Assembly wurde bei Suche im GAC gefunden.
LOG: Die Bindung war erfolgreich. Assembly wird zurückgegeben von C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Siemens.Sinumerik.Operate.Services.Wrapper\4.8.2.0__bdd90fa02fd1c4ee\Siemens.Sinumerik.Operate.Services.Wrapper.dll.
LOG: Die Assembly wird im default-Load-Kontext geladen.
```

Here is the "**WhereRefBind!Host=(LocalMachine)!FileName=(Siemens.Sinumerik.Operate.Services.Wrapper.dll).HTM**":

```
*** Protokolleintrag für Assembly-Binder  (13.12.2019 @ 12:14:00) ***

Der Vorgang wurde durchgeführt.
Ergebnis der Bindung: hr = 0x0. Der Vorgang wurde erfolgreich beendet.

Der Assemblymanager wurde geladen aus:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Als EXE-Datei ausgeführt.  C:\Projekte\MTF\trunk\MTFMain\MTF\bin\Debug\MTF.exe
--- Ein detailliertes Fehlerprotokoll folgt. 

=== Zustandsinformationen vor Bindung ===
LOG: Where-ref-Bindung. Speicherort = C:\Projekte\MTF\trunk\MTFMain\MTF\bin\Debug\dll\Siemens.Sinumerik.Operate.Services.Wrapper.dll
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Projekte/MTF/trunk/MTFMain/MTF/bin/Debug/
LOG: Ursprünglicher PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: DynamicBase = NULL
LOG: CacheBase = NULL
LOG: AppName = MTF.exe
Aufruf von Assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: Diese Bindung startet im LoadFrom-Load-Kontext.
WRN: Das native Image wird nicht im LoadFrom-Kontext durchsucht. Das native Image wird nur im Standard-Load-Kontext durchsucht, z. B. Assembly.Load().
LOG: Die Anwendungskonfigurationsdatei wird verwendet: C:\Projekte\MTF\trunk\MTFMain\MTF\bin\Debug\MTF.exe.Config
LOG: Die Hostkonfigurationsdatei wird verwendet: 
LOG: Die Computerkonfigurationsdatei von C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config wird verwendet.
LOG: Download von neuem URL file:///C:/Projekte/MTF/trunk/MTFMain/MTF/bin/Debug/dll/Siemens.Sinumerik.Operate.Services.Wrapper.dll.
LOG: Der Assembly-Download wurde durchgeführt. Datei-Setup wird begonnen: C:\Projekte\MTF\trunk\MTFMain\MTF\bin\Debug\dll\Siemens.Sinumerik.Operate.Services.Wrapper.dll.
LOG: Die von der Quelle ausgeführte Setup-Phase beginnt.
LOG: Der Assemblyname ist: Siemens.Sinumerik.Operate.Services.Wrapper, Version=4.8.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bdd90fa02fd1c4ee.
LOG: Die Richtlinie wird für where-ref-Bindung erneut angewendet.
LOG: Verweis nach der Richtlinie: Siemens.Sinumerik.Operate.Services.Wrapper, Version=4.8.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bdd90fa02fd1c4ee
LOG: Die Assembly wurde bei Suche im GAC gefunden.
LOG: Wechseln vom LoadFrom-Kontext zum Standardkontext.
LOG: Die Bindung war erfolgreich. Assembly wird zurückgegeben von C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Siemens.Sinumerik.Operate.Services.Wrapper\4.8.2.0__bdd90fa02fd1c4ee\Siemens.Sinumerik.Operate.Services.Wrapper.dll.
LOG: Die Assembly wird im default-Load-Kontext geladen.
```

I hope someone can help me narrowing down the loading issue with the Wrapper assembly :) or have any other ideas what i can do else..

**Thank you so far!!
Let me know if you need some futher information!**

Comment: You may need to finde the DLL in the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory the Windows Service is running on another location

Comment: Hey, i already set base directory to the path of the executable. Like you see in the "fuslogvw" `LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Projekte/MTF/trunk/MTFMain/MTF/bin/Debug/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Root-Cause:**
The issue was caused due to not all native dlls (used ny the mentions wrapper) could be resolved for the "LocalSystem" account.

Big Point was that the Wrapper expects 3 specific paths to be set for finding native dlls e.g. "QT" libs, .. I made this once within the first installation of the this "Siemens" API, BUT as the installation maps its installation-folder with an additional drive letter, I added those 3 additional Paths in the %PATHS% variable using the newly created drive letter -> this was a big issue CAUSE the user "LocalSystem" had no access to my ?virtual? drive "D:"
-> thus the paths within the %PATH% variable could not be "resolved" as drive "D:" didn't exits.

**Solution:** Changed the 3 specific paths in the %PATH% variable to ensure it points to installation folder under "C:.." now!

**ADDITIONAL:**
The tool "procmon" was the only way to see that those native c/c++ libraries could not be resolved. 
I checked all paths the tool listed while searching for e.g. "QtCore4.dll" (while running as service).

-> In general: .NET assemblies to be loaded with "Assembly.Load" will not throw any "AssemblyResolve" event if a native library could not be resolved.

-> Fuslogvw could not help at this level, cause it didn't give these detailed information about native libraries.

**CASE CLOSED :)**